# c# regex repetition count cannot be a variable

Tags: c#, regex

I don't know the repetition count until run time and ending up with ugly code like the below. Is there a way to make the repetition count a variable or somehow less messy? I tried several things including concatenating together a string for mPattern. I ended up with embedded backlashes '\' that was becoming more costly to remove.

```
if (ExtraColumnCount == 0) mPattern = @"\w+(?:\s+(?:\w|#|-)+){3}$";
if (ExtraColumnCount == 1) mPattern = @"\w+(?:\s+(?:\w|#|-)+){4}$";
if (ExtraColumnCount == 2) mPattern = @"\w+(?:\s+(?:\w|#|-)+){5}$";
if (ExtraColumnCount == 3) mPattern = @"\w+(?:\s+(?:\w|#|-)+){6}$";
```

Comment: Maybe adjust the quantifier like `$@"\w+(?:\s+[\w#-]+){{{ExtraColumnCount+3}}}$"`?

Comment: You could get all the last columns into a Capture Collecton, then join what you need at the end ? `(\w+)(\s+[\w#-]+)+$` The problem here is that you've got two pinch points where you force `\w` only as a starter ( [\w#-] internally), butted up against the EOS `$`. These are validation points that raise red flags. I would re-evaluate the regex's usage.

Answer (score 1):

`mPattern` is a string so you can simply do:

```
mPattern = @"\w+(?:\s+(?:\w|#|-)+){"+ (ExtraColumnCount+3).ToString() +"}$";
```

Comment: That actually works. I had something like that to begin with but insude the mPattern variable, I was thrown off by the extra slashes. I guess that is how it should be. Example: "\\w+(?:\\s+(?:\\w|#|-)+){8}$"

Comment: @user2741445, Well, we all make simple mistakes, glad it helped